# Nested subqueries with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Using Ecto v2.2.6, Phoenix 1.3

I have a Blog app with a Newsfeed.  It works like this:

- Users can submit Posts.
- Users can follow other Users.
- When a user submits a Post, an item in the Newsfeed table is added.
- Users can see a newsfeed of Posts that have been submitted by Users they are following.

I want to use Ecto.Query to get a list of newsfeed items from users that a given user is following.

---

Quick background.  Here are the objects:

#### User

```
mix phx.gen.json Accounts User users email:string password:string
```

#### Post

```
mix phx.gen.json Content Post posts title:string content:string user_id:references:users
```

(`users` and `posts` have a `has_many:` and `belongs_to:` relationship.)

#### Follow

```
mix phx.gen.json Accounts Follow follows following_id:references:users followed_id:references:users
```

(When user A follows user B, a new `Follow` entry is created where `following_id` points to A, and `followed_id` points to B.)

#### Newsfeed

```
mix phx.gen.json Content Newsfeeditem newsfeeditems type:string, user_id:integer, content:string
```

---

Now I want to query this stuff.  For me to get a list of `Newsfeeditems` for a given user, it's easy:

import Ecto.Query

```
query =
  from n in Newsfeeditem,
    where: n.user_id == ^user_id
```

Let's say I'm user 1, and I am following users 2, 3 and 4.  There are three entries in the `follows` table.  To get all the corresponding newsfeeditems for those users, the query would look something like this:

```
query =
  from n in Newsfeeditem,
    where: n.user1_id in [2,3,4]
```

I want to make it dynamic.  Here's where I am lost.  I would like to do something that resembles this:

```
subquery =
  from f in Follow,
    where: f.following_id == 1,
    select: f.follower_id

query =
  from n in Newsfeeditem,
    where: n.user_id in (Repo.all(subquery))
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to structure these things correctly.

How can I select this via subquery? (**Note** I'm looking for the subquery solution specifically, but bonus points if there is a better way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Subquerys are currently not allowed in `where` clauses; the documentation recommends using a JOIN instead.](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/da796bc005885592f48ba9c1286971ce54a8ff05/lib/ecto/query.ex#L417-L418) Your query can be converted to a JOIN quite easily. I haven't tested it but this should work:

```
query =
  from f in Follow,
    where: f.following_id == 1,
    join: n in Newsfeeditem,
    on: n.user_id == f.follower_id,
    select: n
```